# Validar que los datos introducidos sean decimales y entén entre unos rangos específicos con c#

Tags: c#

Habían publicado creo que ayer mismo ésta pregunta

Como evaluar que los datos recibidos sean decimales sin usar una excepción y que esos datos, que son dos valores A y B estén entre los siguientes rangos:

Valor A entre -150 y 150

Valor B entre -100 y 100

Hoy me puse a trabajar en ello y después de haber logrado el código que lo evaluaba, al ponerme a publicar la respuesta, me encuentro con que había sido eliminada por el autor

Así que aprovechando que ya tenía el código me contestaré a mi mismo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí hay una opción utilizando `Decimal.TryParse (string s, out decimal result);` Link a la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Decimal__).

```
var valorA = "2.36";
var valorB = "125.6";
var valorC = "Esto no es decimal";

var decimalA = 0.0M;
var decimalB = 0.0M;
var decimalC = 0.0M;

var esDecimalA = decimal.TryParse(valorA, out decimalA);
var esDecimalB = decimal.TryParse(valorB, out decimalB);
var esDecimalC = decimal.TryParse(valorC, out decimalC);

if (esDecimalA)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El valor '{valorA}' {((decimalA < 150 && decimalA > -150) ? "Sí está dentro del rango" : "No está dentro del rango")}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El valor' {valorA}' no es un número decimal ");
}

if (esDecimalB)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El valor '{valorB}' {((decimalB < 100 && decimalB > -100) ? "Sí está dentro del rango" : "No está dentro del rango")}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El valor '{valorB}' no es un número decimal ");
}

if (esDecimalC)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El valor '{valorC}' {((decimalC < 100 && decimalC > -100) ? "Sí está dentro del rango" : "No está dentro del rango")}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine($"El valor '{valorC}' no es un número decimal ");
}
```

Copia y pega esto dentro del `static void Main(string[] args)` en una nueva aplicación de consola y lo corres para que compruebes los resultados:

```
El valor '2.36' Sí está dentro del rango
El valor '125.6' No está dentro del rango
El valor 'Esto no es decimal' no es un número decimal
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo pido los valores por consola, pero se supone que en su programa los recibiría de alguna parte del programa, de ahí que no meta en un bucle la evaluación de los valores hasta que alcancen los rangos de valores permitidos y me limite a decir si está o no entre los rangos solicitados

Para evaluar que los datos dados por teclado sean decimales, al no poder usar la excepción, pues era uno de los requisitos solicitados en la pregunta, uso una evaluación para que al recorrer los valores de string que corresponden con los números decimales dados por teclado contentan el punto de separación decimal.

éste era el código que se me había ocurrido

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{        
    //instanciamos la clase escaner
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    //creamos dos variables string que recogeran los datos introducidos por teclado
    String cadA = "", cadB = "";
    
    //creamos una variable booleana a false
    boolean valorA = false;
    //mienstras esa variable sea false
    while (!valorA){       
        //pedimos por consola en valor de A
        System.out.println("Ponga el valor A");
        //capturamos ese valor como string y lo almacenamos en la variable cadA
        cadA = teclado.nextLine();
        //Llamamos al método para comprobar que sea decimal y recibimos true o false
        valorA = metodoComprobarDecimales(cadA);
        //si es false lo informamos el usuario
        if (!valorA){
            //se imprime el aviso
            System.out.println("El valor A no es un valor Decimal");
        }
    }
    //creamos una variable booleana a false
    boolean valorB = false;
    //mienstras esa variable sea false
    while (!valorB){      
        //pedimos por consola en valor de A
        System.out.println("Ponga el valor B");
        //capturamos ese valor como string y lo almacenamos en la variable cadB
        cadB = teclado.nextLine();
        //Llamamos al método para comprobar que sea decimal y recibimos true o false
        valorB = metodoComprobarDecimales(cadB);
        //si es false lo informamos el usuario
        if (!valorB){
            //se imprime el aviso
            System.out.println("El valor B no es un valor Decimal");
        }
    }
    
    //cremoas variables doubles de cada valor y convertimos los string
    double cadDoA = Double.parseDouble(cadA); 
    double cadDoB = Double.parseDouble(cadB); 

    //creamos un array bolleano para recibir la respuesta de comprobar que los valores estén entre los parámetros solicitados
    boolean[] valores = metodoComprobarValores(cadDoA, cadDoB);

    //si los valors son corectos continúa el programa
    if (valores[0] && valores[1]){
        System.out.println("Continuamos sin problemas");
    }
}
//método que comprueba que los valores introducidos sean decimales
public static boolean metodoComprobarDecimales(String valor){
    //creamos variable booleana a false
    boolean hayPunto = false;
    //variable entera para el número de caracteres del string
    int n = valor.length();

    //un bule limitado por el número de caracteres
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        //si contiene un punto como separador de decimales
        if ( valor.charAt(i) == '.'){                       
            //almacenamos true en la variable
            hayPunto = true;
        }          
    }
    //retornamos  la variable
    return hayPunto;
}
//método que comprueba que los valores estén entre los rangos especificados que recibe ambos valores por parámetro
public static boolean[] metodoComprobarValores(double A, double B){
    //creamos el array de boolean para recibir los valores true o false de cada valor
    boolean[] valores = new boolean[2];
    //vaibles booleanas para ambos valores
    boolean valorA = false;
    boolean valorB = false;
    //valor improbable que damos a la variable valor double
    double valor = 999999999;
    //variable contador a cero
    int contador = 0;
    
    //mientras contador sea menor que 2
    while (contador < 2){
        //si la variable valor tiene el dato improbable
        if (valor == 999999999){
            //asignamos el valor de A a valor
            valor = A;
            //si A es mayor de -150 y menor de 150
            if (valor > -150.0 && valor < 150.0){                       
                //variable a true
                valorA = true;
                //almacenamos ese true en el array en la posición 0
                valores[0] = valorA;
            //si no está en el rango
            }else{
                //damos la noticia al usuario
                System.out.println("Valor A fuera de rango");
            }
        }
        //si el valor contenido en la variable no es el improbable, se supone que es A y ésta ya ha sido comprobada
        else {
            //así que asignamos el valor de B a valor
            valor = B;
            //si su valor está entre -100 y 100
            if (valor > -100.0 && valor < 100.0){                       
                //almacenamos true en la variable
                valorB = true;
                //almacenamos true en la posición 1 del array
                valores[1] = valorB;
            //si no está en los rangos de valores permitidos
            }else{
                //informamos al usuario
                System.out.println("Valor B fuera de rango");
            }
        }      
        //incrementamos el contador en 1
        contador++;
    }
    //retornamos el array
    return valores;
}
```

Comment: Por qué no utilizaste `Decimal.TryParse()`? De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Decimal__), te devuelve `true` cuando sí es decimal y luego evalúas si está dentro del rango.

Comment: Pues la verdad @Arriel, porque desconocía el método. Gracias por mostrarlo